# headerclick event not working on gridpanel using extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I'm trying to invoke headerclick event using ext js listener but unable to invoke.

here is my code:

```
var myGrid = Ext.Create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: 'shrGrid',
    renderTo: myGrid,
    store: myStore, //JSON object
    columns: myGrid.columns, //JSON object
    viewConfig: {
        listeners: {
            cellclick: function (view, cell, cellIndex, record, row,     rowIndex, e) {
                alert("cell clicked");
            },
            headerclick function (shrGrid, columns , e, t, eOpts) {
                alert("header clicked");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Here the cellclick is being invoked without any issue.
but headerclick is neither being invoked neither nor giving any error.
I just used headerclick here only. pls help me I missed anything or give me some example link.

Answer (score 0):

Your `myGrid.columns` probably looks something like this:

```
columns : [{
    header : 'Name',
    dataIndex : 'name',
    sortable : false,
    field : {
        allowBlank : false
    }
}, {
    id: 'headerid', //Set your id here
    header : 'Description',
    dataIndex : 'description',
    sortable : false,
    field : {}
}, {
    header : 'Order',
    width : 40,
    dataIndex : 'sortOrder',
    hidden : true
}, {
    header : '',
    dataIndex : 'id',
    width : 30,
    fixed : true,
    sortable : false,
    hideable : false,
    align : 'center',
    renderer : function (v, p, r) {
        return "<img alt='Delete this record' src='images/icons/delete.gif'>";
    }
}],
```

If you do that you can access the id and add a listener like this

```
var myGrid = Ext.Create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: 'shrGrid',
    renderTo: myGrid,
    store: myStore, //JSON object
    columns: myGrid.columns, //JSON object
    viewConfig: {
         listeners: {
            render: function(component) {
                 Ext.get('headerid').on('click',function() { //reference the id you defined for the column header
                     alert('header clicked');
                 });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have JSON object for headers of myGrid. How can we find the which column is being clicked.                                                                                   Could you please help me how we can pass the headerid ?

Comment: Have you looked at whats available for `this`?